# What could cause a variable to behave as infinite and simultaneously as non-infinite?

Tags: opengl, glsl

To learn opengl, I'm creating a simple 3D graphics engine using openGL 3.3.  I've recently added light attenuation over distance; this has turned all objects completely black.  This was done by adding the following code to my light calculations in the fragment shader:

```
float distance = length(lite.position - FragPos);
float attenuation = 1.0f/(lite.constant + (lite.linear * distance) + (lite.quadratic * (distance * distance)));
ambient *= attenuation;
diffuse *= attenuation;
specular *= attenuation;

result += (ambient + diffuse + specular);
```

It seems safe to assume that `attenuation` is very small, effectively or actually 0, or negative (black).  To test this I use `result += vec3(attenuation);`, the result of this is white objects; this then indicates that `attenuation` is not near 0 and instead 1.0 or larger; an additional test trying `result += vec3(attenuation/500000);` still produces white, which indicates that attenuation is quite large, perhaps infinite.  I did some infinity and NaN checks on it.  NaN checks told me it is a number, infinity checks tell me it is sometimes infinite and sometimes isn't.  In fact it told me that it is both infinite and not infinite at the same time.  I determined this by using the following code segment:

```
if(isinf(attenuation)){
  result += vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
if(isinf(attenuation) && !isinf(attenuation)){
  result += vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
if(!isinf(attenuation)){
  result += vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My objects turned purple/magenta.  Were `attenuation` infinite, I would expect my objects to appear red; were they not infinite, I would expect them to appear blue; were they somehow both infinite and not infinite I would expect them to appear green.  If I make the `result += ...` to be `result = ...`, the objects appear red.  In this case, were it both infinite and not infinite, as my purple objects suggest, `result` would first be set to red, and then set to blue, resulting in blue objects (if somehow the green check fails).

I hope this describes the source of my confusion.  My testing shows that `attenuation` is infinite, and that it is not infinite, AND that it is neither.

To top everything off when I use:

```
float attenuation = 1.0f/(1.0 + (0.0014 * distance) + (0.000007* (distance * distance)));
```

to determine the attenuation factor, everything works exactly as expected; however the values shown here as constants are exactly what's passed in from my openGL calls (c++):

```
glUniform1f(lightConstantLoc,  1.0f);
glUniform1f(lightLinearLoc,    0.0014f);
glUniform1f(lightQuadraticLoc, 0.000007f);
```

From there I should conclude that my data is not being delivered to my shaders correctly, however I'm confident my `lite.constant` etc values have been set correctly, and that `distance` is a reasonable value.  When I single each one out as a color, the objects do turn that color.i.e.: using this

```
result = vec3(lite.constant, 0.0, 0.0);
```

my objects turn some shade of red, for `lite.constant`, `lite.linear` etc.

Searching google and stack overflow for things like "glsl isinf true and false" or "glsl variable is and isn't infinite" gives me absolutely no relevant results.

I get the feeling I'm distinctly ignorant of something happening here, or the way something works.  And so I turn to you, am I missing something obvious, doing this all wrong, or is this a true mystery?

Comment: could you set `result` in your test to vec3(0, 0, 0) beforehand, to make sure it's not a prior value messing things up?  (it being magenta makes no sense)

Comment: @Clairvoire Thank you for mentioning to reset `result`, it brought my attention to the solution.  `result` was set to `vec3(0.0)` before the loop that iterated across all light sources.  Problem is, the loop iterated more times than there were lights, and so it was using non-existent data.  I'll be posting an answer to this effect soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in code that is not shown in the question.
The crucial piece of information is that my shader supports up to 5 light sources, and iterates across all 5 of them; even when fewer than 5 light sources are provided.  With this in mind changing

```
vec3 result = vec3(0.0);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
  Light lite = light[i];
  ...
```

to

```
vec3 result = vec3(0.0);
for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i){
  Light lite = light[i];
  ...
```

solves the problem, and everything now behaves perfectly.  It seems that data that does not exist is neither infinite nor finite; which makes sense to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your attenuation is so large, but the explanation for your is/isn't infinite issue is simple -- at least one component of `attenuation` is infinite, while at least one of the other components is not.

When you do `if (bvec)` -- testing a condition that is a boolean vector rather than a single boolean -- it acts as if you did `if (any(bvec))`.  So it will execute the associated true branch if any of the components are true.  When you have `isinf(attenuation)`, you get a boolean vector.  For example, if the red is inifinite and the others are not, you'll get (true, false, false).  So `!isinf(attenuation)` will be (false, true, true), and the result of the `&&` in the middle `if` is (false, false, false).

So it executes the first and third if (and not the second), giving you magenta.

Comment: In the posted code, `attenuation` is a scalar float. Does this explanation really apply in the case of a scalar value?

Comment: This would describe the problem perfectly, were `attenuation` a vector, but as has been pointed out `attenuation` is actually a `float`/scalar.  Does this explanation apply, or is there a way my `float` is being confused as a `bvec`?